How can I expand a regex to find the entire URL in these cases?
I need to match complete blogger.googleusercontent.com image link URLs that include the /img/a/ subdirectories. The URLs are for images, and the file names don't have file extensions, but that may not matter.
These are two sample URLs from a large text file dump of HTML. There is a lot of HTML markup, but there are spaces before href and after the closing " of the URLs.
href="https://blogger.googleusercontent.com/img/a/AVvXsEhb-vB59M2NTWyWvDlMemRdgT0XMKdjB4NMH02iP4Nb7HbzHwq5ZObxjEC1_oLne6xpUhIkrkpyWEdMX9ck-aU5h1JXdpSw-GhbV90QBEi2xigGLQdoSswWuQtPNNCyWMRJiT2XnEadx170jUDbtL-AQKKzYyarCoj8=s1727"
src="https://blogger.googleusercontent.com/img/a/AVvXsEhb-vB59M2NTWyWvDlMemRdgT0XMKdjB4NMH02iP4Nb7HbzHwq5ZObxjEC1_oLne6xpUhIkrkpyWEdMX9ck-aU5h1JXdpSw-GhbV90QBEi2xigGLQdoSswWuQtPNNCyWMRJiT2XnEadx170jUDbtL-AQKKzYyarCoj8=w400-h183"
What I am using is this:
\/img\/a\/[^\/]

And that matches
/img/a/A
I don't need to match the capital A, as I also need to change the regex to also find images in /img/b/
But I do need to expand the match to find the entire URL, from https to the end ".
Fiddle: https://regex101.com/r/txLWcO/1

Try: https?:\/\/.*\/img\/a\/[^"]+?

try: https://regex101.com/r/GJMTmR/1 ?  (using regexp: https:\/\/blogger.googleusercontent.com\/img\/a\/[^\/"]+)

@Luuk Thanks! That works. It also sometimes picks up ' height='72' width='72' but that's because some URLs end in a single quote, not a double quote. Add this as an answer.

Or exclude matching a single quote, double quote and whitespace characters https:\/\/blogger\.googleusercontent\.com\/img\/a\/[^\/\s'"]+ and if you don't have to escape forward slashes in bbedit then https://blogger\.googleusercontent\.com/img/a/[^/\s'"]+

@Thefourthbird Thanks! That works in BBEdit. Add that as an answer and I will accept it. One little bug; for some reason, the regex doesn't expand to the full URL when I search for /img/b/ rather than /img/a/.

You could use:
https://blogger\.googleusercontent\.com/img/a/[^/\s'"]+

The pattern matches:

https://blogger\.googleusercontent\.com/img/a/ Match https://blogger.googleusercontent.com/img/a/ escaping the dots to match them literally
[^/\s'"]+ Match 1+ non whitespace characters excluding " and '

(Or use * to match zero or more occurrences instead of +)
See a regex demo
If you want to match either /a/ or /b/ you can use a character class
https://blogger\.googleusercontent\.com/img/[ab]/[^/\s'"]+


Thanks! That works great for /a/ links. I found an edge case that I can't figure out for /b/ links; the regex doesn't expand, and src="// may or may not be the cause: https://regex101.com/r/QAXLFL/1

@BlueDogRanch Then you could update it to //blogger\.googleusercontent\.com/img/[ab]/[^\s'"]+ See https://regex101.com/r/kvYo6V/1
